# I am not able to get the authorization code from program

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

So I am working on a coding project for my internship in DC. My project involves using python and microsoft graph api to build a program that checks the email addresses of employees obtained at my company to see if another authorization method has been added to the email address. If another authorization method is detected for an email address, it could mean that someone/a bad actor is trying to access information.

I have been referring to the video *Getting Started With Microsoft Graph API For Python Development (Set Up & Authentication)* by Jie Jenn. So far, I'm able to get a device code and link from the program, but I cannot obtain the authorization code. Aside from that, I am also getting a traceback error in line 31 of demo2.py, another 2 traceback errors in line 12 and 100 of main.py, and TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable in demo2.py.

Here is my code.

Thank You,
Sairam

Errors:

'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\S.Soundararajan\Documents\PE Project for Azure\demo2.py", line 31, in 
webbrowser.open(flow('verification_uri'))
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
'''

'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\S.Soundararajan\Documents\PE Project for Azure\main.py", line 100, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\S.Soundararajan\Documents\PE Project for Azure\main.py", line 12, in main
graph: Graph = Graph(azure_settings)
TypeError: Graph() takes no arguments
Python Graph Tutorial
'''

demo2.py:

`

```
#import account as account
import webbrowser 
from xmlrpc.client import APPLICATION_ERROR
import requests
import msal
from msal import PublicClientApplication

CLIENT_ID = ''
CLIENT_SECRET = ''
authority_url = ''
base_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/'

endpoint = base_url + 'me'
SCOPES = ['User.Read', 'Mail.Read', 'Mail.Send']

# Method 2. Login to acquire access_token
app = PublicClientApplication(
    CLIENT_ID,
    authority = authority_url
)

#accounts = app.get_accounts()
#if accounts:
    #app.acquire_token_silent(scopes=SCOPES, account=account[0])

flow = app.initiate_device_flow(scopes=SCOPES)
print(flow)
print(flow['message'])
#app_code = flow['message']
webbrowser.open(flow('verification_uri'))

result = app.acquire_token_by_device_flow(flow)
access_token_id = result['access_token']
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer' + access_token_id}


response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)
print(response)
print(response.json())
```

`

main.py:

```
    import configparser
    from graph import Graph
    from msal import PublicClientApplication
    def main():
        print('Python Graph Tutorial\n')

        # Load settings
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(['config.cfg', 'config.dev.cfg'])
        azure_settings = config['azure']
    
        graph: Graph = Graph(azure_settings)

        greet_user(graph)

        choice = -1

        while choice != 0:
            print('Please choose one of the following options:')
            print('0. Exit')
            print('1. Display access token')
            print('2. List my inbox')
            print('3. Send mail')
            print('4. List users (requires app-only)')
            print('5. Make a Graph call')

            try:
                choice = int(input())
            except ValueError:
                choice = -1

            if choice == 0:
                print('Goodbye...')
            elif choice == 1:
                display_access_token(graph)
            elif choice == 2:
                list_inbox(graph)
            elif choice == 3:
                send_mail(graph)
            elif choice == 4:
                list_users(graph)
            elif choice == 5:
                make_graph_call(graph)
            else:
                print('Invalid choice!\n')

    def greet_user(graph: Graph):
        user = graph.get_user()
        print('Hello,', user['displayName'])
        # For Work/school accounts, email is in mail property
        # Personal accounts, email is in userPrincipalName
        print('Email:', user['mail'] or user['userPrincipalName'], '\n')

    def display_access_token(graph: Graph):
        token = graph.get_user_token()
        print('User token:', token, '\n')
        return 1

    def list_users(graph: Graph):
        users_page = graph.get_users()

        # Output each users's details
            for user in users_page['value']:
                print('User:', user['displayName'])
                print('  ID:', user['id'])
                print('  Email:', user['mail'])

        # If @odata.nextLink is present
        more_available = '@odata.nextLink' in users_page
        print('\nMore users available?', more_available, '\n')

    def list_inbox(graph: Graph):
            message_page = graph.get_inbox()

            # Output each message's details
            for message in message_page['value']:
                print('Message:', message['subject'])
                print('  From:', message['from']['emailAddress']['name'])
                print('  Status:', 'Read' if message['isRead'] else 'Unread')
                print('  Received:', message['receivedDateTime'])

            # If @odata.nextLink is present
            more_available = '@odata.nextLink' in message_page
            print('\nMore messages available?', more_available, '\n')


    def send_mail(graph: Graph):
        # Send mail to the signed-in user
        # Get the user for their email address
        user = graph.get_user()
        user_email = user['mail'] or user['userPrincipalName']

        graph.send_mail('Testing Microsoft Graph', 'Hello world!', user_email)
        print('Mail sent.\n')

    def make_graph_call(graph: Graph):
        graph.make_graph_call()

    # Run main
    main()


`
```

Comment: Can you please post the error traceback you are getting alongside the code?

Comment: I updated it to include the errors

Answer (score 1):

**Issue1:**

On the code base, the mentioned url is not declared yet, and flow was not able to find it to be executed.

Usually, the key-value pair should always use square brackets to access the value inside. One of the codes mentioned in the thread is needed to use [] to access elements of a dictionary. Not `()`  else will get the TypeError: The "dict" object is not callable error.

[image]

**Solution:**

```
authority_url= 'https://docs.python.org/'
webbrowser.open_new(authority_url) // same window
webbrowser.open_new_tab(authority_url) // will open in new tab
```

**Issue 2:**

refer this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/microsoft-graph?view=azure-python).

Comment: I have the CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, and authority_url. But I didn't put it on here because that is confidential information for my company. I'd be putting them at risk if I included that information here on stackoverflow